# How do I round a C# datetime to datetime2(0)

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my integration tests I am trying to compare a C# DateTime that was inserted into a column that is defined as `datetime2(0)` so obviously it loses precision on the way back out from the DB.

So my question is how do I round a C# `DateTime` to `datetime2(0)` precision?

I'd like to be able to go

`Assert.AreEqual(insert.CreatedDateTimeUtc.RoundDateTime2(0), result.CreatedDateTimeUtc)`

```
declare @datetime2 datetime2(0);

set @datetime2 = '2014-04-08 10:27:36.000';
print @datetime2

set @datetime2 = '2014-04-08 10:27:36.499';
print @datetime2

set @datetime2 = '2014-04-08 10:27:36.500';
print @datetime2

set @datetime2 = '2014-04-08 10:27:36.999';
print @datetime2

-- Prints
2014-04-08 10:27:36
2014-04-08 10:27:36
2014-04-08 10:27:37
2014-04-08 10:27:37
```

Comment: What is `datetime2(0)`?  That's not a .NET class, is it?

Comment: Its a data type in SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NUnits EqualConstraint:

> DateTimes and TimeSpans may be compared either with or without a
>   tolerance. A tolerance is specified using Within with either a
>   TimeSpan as an argument or with a numeric value followed by a one of
>   the time conversion modifiers: Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds,
>   Milliseconds or Ticks.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.5

```
[TestFixture]
public class DateTime2Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestRoundDateTime2_RoundsDown_000()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36, 000);
        var xxxx = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36);
        Assert.That(xxxx, Is.EqualTo(date).Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestRoundDateTime2_RoundsDown_499()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36, 499);
        var xxxx = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36);
        Assert.That(xxxx, Is.EqualTo(date).Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestRoundDateTime2_RoundsUp_500()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36, 500);
        var xxxx = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 37);
        Assert.That(xxxx, Is.EqualTo(date).Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestRoundDateTime2_RoundsUp_750()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36, 750);
        var xxxx = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 37);
        Assert.That(xxxx, Is.EqualTo(date).Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestRoundDateTime2_RoundsUp999()
    {
        var date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 36, 999);
        var xxxx = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 10, 27, 37);
        Assert.That(xxxx, Is.EqualTo(date).Within(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to transfer the date.Kind to your new rounded date.

Answer (score 3):

Edited to perform rounding...

So:

```
long tickOfSecond = original.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
long ticksToAdd = tickOfSecond < TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 2
         ? -tickOfSecond : 10000000 - tickOfSecond
DateTime truncated = original.PlusTicks(ticksToAdd);
```

Comment: SQL Server rounds up and down based on the millisecond component

Answer (score 0):

`datetime2(0)` defines a datetime with no fractional seconds, e.g. milliseconds always equals 0.  There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

```
var rounded = new DateTime(
    original.Ticks - (original.Millisecond * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond)
);
```

Comment: Sorry this was a typo.

Comment: I think sql server is rounding the seconds up. 
Expected: 2014-04-08 22:03:18.000
But was:  2014-04-08 22:03:19.000

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway - it assumes that the value is on an exact millisecond boundary. (Consider `new DateTime(1)` - that will be "rounded" to itself.)